# Problema ao gerar ssh key no git lab

Tags: git, gitlab

Gente estou tentando gerar um ssh key para usar no meu gitlab mais fica dando esse erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o git bash para gerar o key utilizando esse comando : ssh-keygen oque pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: qual foi o caminho percorrido para você gerar a ssh key?

Comment: @LeonardoTheodoro segui esses passos https://bigdataagronegocio.wordpress.com/2017/03/11/tutorial-de-instalacao-e-configuracao-do-gitlab-no-windows/

Comment: tente usar esse comando para gerar sua ssh key `ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"`. Como você está no windows, após ter gerado, use esse comando para copiar sua SSH key `cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub | clip`. Após ter copiado, tente colar sua nova SSH e verifique se deu certo!

Comment: @LeonardoTheodoro continua dando erro me salva hahahaha por favor

Comment: The form contains the following errors:
Fingerprint has already been taken
Fingerprint cannot be generated
Key type is forbidden. Must be RSA, ECDSA, or ED25519

Answer (score -1):

Remove o `Usuario@Usuario-PC`do final, porque isso não pertence a chave ssh.

Segue os passos da documentação: https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-no-Servidor-Gerando-Sua-Chave-P%C3%BAblica-SSH

Que ela vai servir para qualquer sistema operacional e quando repositório.

Comment: O link que você enviou da documentação possui o `Usuario@Usuario-PC` no exemplo mostrado.

Comment: Mas isso não interfere, isso não precisa colocar, a indentificaçao do computador.

Comment: Realmente é desnecessário, já vi com e sem dependendo da situação. Mas será que tirar nesse caso resolve o problema dele...

Comment: eu sempre uso sem no Gitub e Bitbucket, não lembro se no GitLab é assim?

Answer (score -3):

Já existe um fingerprint cadastrado.Então você precisa excluir o outro e também é bom tirar espaços desnecessários só para garantir, assim: [Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMB9u.png)